# Qt plugins in Mathematica 12.1

Tags: linux, installation

I recently upgraded to version 12.1. When running from terminal, program crashes, with the following error:

```
Qt issued a fatal error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Qt tried to load plugins from: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/Qt/plugins /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64

Mathematica was installed in /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1 /usr/local/bin/mathematica: line 138: 20411 Aborted                 (core dumped) "${MathematicaFE}" ${MESA_FLAG} -topDirectory "${TopDirectory}" "$@"
```

No idea how to proceed. Version 12.0 did not have any problems. Using Fedora Linux 31.

Comment: You should contact tech support for this.

Comment: I use the same linux distribution and both versions work fine.

Comment: Do you use Matlab R2019b/R2020a? I only encountered this failure when Matlab is in the path. In my case, the QT-library is hijacked by Matlab. Removing Matlab from the path, and Mathematica starts in the Frontend mode without problems. The solution below solves now the problem of a data transfer while relying on MATLink.

Comment: Nope, no Matlab in my system.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments, I got in touch with Wolfram support. After a couple of iterations, we found out that the problem was solved by adding a new environment variable:

```
export USE_WOLFRAM_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=1
```

After this, I could run version 12.1 without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Stilgar's solution works. However, it is also recommended to install the missing Qt5 libraries and other dependencies as mentioned here:

https://support.wolfram.com/59044